# How do I get rid of the 'Shared Y-STAT not available’ message that appears at logon? (CMS on z/VM)

Tags: virtual-machine

This happens on all my CMS guests on my z/VM 7.20 system, running on a z14. I have tried REIPLing but that hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Shared S-STAT not available' or 'Shared Y-STAT not available' messages appear at logon when either the 190 S-disk or 19E Y-disk respectively were changed *after* the CMS NSS was last saved. You just need to rebuild the CMS NSS to make these go away.

To rebuild the CMS NSS:

1. Logon to the MAINTrvm service ID for your release. Ex: For z/VM 7.20: MAINT720.
2. Issue `PUT2PROD SAVECMS`